SwiftUI view extension modifier pattern like "view.disabled(true)"
I'm trying to add an extension to modify the behavior of a custom swiftui view, similar to what you do with the disabled extension function:
Button("Title") { do something }
     .disabled(true)

I will oversimplify what Im trying to do with the code below, (comments in line).
 // The custom view is a horizontal paging view, for simplicity I just added a Stack with the value of a @State variable that would change the behavior to disable scrolling.
 struct MyHorizontalScroll: View {
    @State fileprivate var disableScroll = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Disable Scroll: \(disableScroll)")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

In this extension I add a method called disableScroll that should allow the caller to either disable or enable the scroll
extension MyHorizontalScroll {
    func disableScroll(_ disable: Bool) -> some View {
        self.disableScroll = disable
        // /Note that the disableScroll state variable does not change doesn't matter what I try to set. I've tried setting it directly with self._disableScroll.wrappedValue with the same results.
       // The only thing that works is to copy the view variable and create a new State variable and setting it directly like this:
       /*
       var view = self
       view._disableScroll = State(initialValue: disable)
       return view
       */
        // The commented code above works, but I'm not sure this would be the right thing to do.
        return self
    }
}

An example of the pattern usage.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyHorizontalScroll()
                .disableScroll(true)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

I know I can use a @Bindable variable, but I like the extension modifier pattern. Is there a way to achieve this behavior change with this pattern?

If MyHorizontalScroll itself will not change whether scroll is disabled or not, disableScroll should not be a @State. Just remove @State, and do:
extension MyHorizontalScroll {
    func disableScroll(_ disable: Bool) -> some View {
        var view = self
        view.disableScroll = disable
        return view
    }
}

Alternatively, I find using an initialiser to be more idiomatic if the extension is specifically on MyHorizontalScroll:
struct MyHorizontalScroll: View {
    let disableScroll: Bool
    
    fileprivate init(disableScroll: Bool) {
        self.disableScroll = disableScroll
    }
    
    // only expose this initialiser so that other code can only set disableScroll via the view modifier
    init() {
        self.init(disableScroll: false)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Disable Scroll: \(disableScroll)")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

extension MyHorizontalScroll {
    func disableScroll(_ disable: Bool) -> some View {
        MyHorizontalScroll(disableScroll: disable)
    }
}

In iOS 16+, isScrollEnabled is part of the EnvironmentValues, so you don't need to reinvent your own. Just read it from the environment. Do note that this is the opposite of what you currently have (scrollDisabled), so you would need to invert the logic involving this.
@Environment(\.isScrollEnabled) var scrollEnabled

You can modify this using the built-in scrollDisabled modifier.
.scrollDisabled(true)

If you are using a ScrollView, the environment value is automatically applied to it, so you don't need to do anything extra.
Before iOS 16, you can make your own EnvironmentKey too, and store this in the environment instead of in MyHorizontalScroll itself. See here for an example.

If MyHorizontalScroll itself can change whether it can be scrolled, it should take a @Binding in its initialiser. This sort of disableScroll modifier approach makes little sense.
You can, however, make it a "suggestion" that the caller can make:
// your custom view modifier will set this, either through an initialiser, setting a var, or the environment
let prefersScrollDisabled: Bool

// this is what MyHorizontalScroll will set, when it wants to disable/enable its own scrollability
@State private var scrollable = true

// this is what will be read in the "body"
var shouldScroll: Bool {
    !prefersScrollDisabled && scrollable
}

var body: some View {
    Text("Disable Scroll: \(!shouldScroll)")
}

extension MyHorizontalScroll {
    func prefersScrollDisabled(_ disable: Bool) -> some View {
        MyHorizontalScroll(prefersScrollDisabled: disable)
    }
}


Interesting information thank you. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around using a var without a @State in this case. I understand that we are changing the "blueprint" for the actual view node and we are not changing the implicit position identifier so the view node won't deallocate if I change the value for scrolling. I like it. But as you said its easier with the new disableScroll modifier.
